# Translating expressions with "to care" into French

Tags: expressions, anglais

We use "to care" in a variety of ways in English. I struggle to translate some of these expressions into French.

Examples:

- *Why does she care?* (Significance: Why is she involved when the situation has nothing to do with her?)
- *I can't help them if they don't care.* (Significance: to be involved/interested in helping one's self.)
- *To care about one's community*

Can someone please help with these translations? I'm not sure what I'm missing but I feel like direct translations don't quite get the same point across.

Comment: [FL is not a translation service](http://french.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). Try and give us a specific sentence in French, saying what words or phrases you have problems with, and then you'll get help. Have you tried looking in an [English French dictionary](http://dictionnaire.reverso.net/anglais-francais/care)?

Comment: I think this needs to be edited to fall within our format as described in the help center.

Answer (score 3):

- *Why does she care?*

  "De quoi s'occupe-t'elle ?"

  Implying that you are thinking that she should mind his own business: "Elle devrait s'occuper de ses oignons"   (idiomatic expression).
- *I can't help them if they don't care.*

  "Je ne peux pas les aider s'ils s'en moquent" or (slang) "s'ils s'en foutent".
- *To care about one's community*

  "Prendre soin de sa communauté"

Comment: Graffito! Grand merci! Désolé si j'ai mal utilisé le site. J'habite dans une village au Cameroun et j'ai l'accès limité à l'internet. J'utilise le dictionnaire toujours. Pourtant, quelque fois le dictionnaire ne peut pas aider parce que certaines choses ne peuvent pas être directement traduits. Graffito, merci beaucoup pour ton aide!!